# Select an element by the text it contains with Selenium Webdriver

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I've jjust started off with Selenium Webdriver and I've hit an issuee straight away involving the buttons I'm trying to select/click all have no IDs and share the same class.

So I'm wondering how I select these by the unique text they contain.

I'm thinking possibly with css selector maybe, but I'm unsure how to also tell it to look for specific text to select the element.

All I currently have is:

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Internal;

namespace SeleniumTest1.Methods
{
    public class HomePage
    {

        private readonly IWebDriver _browser;
        public HomePage(IWebDriver browser)
        {
            _browser = browser;
        }

        public IWebElement SearchBox()
        {
            return _browser.FindElement(By.Id("searchBox"));
        }

        public void ImageButton()
        {
            _browser.FindElement(By.CssSelector("a")).Click();
        }

    }
}
```

Very basic so far.

Where I have the CssSelector I'm not sure if theres anyway to say select "a" containing text "xyz".

I've tried search for ways but can't find anything, though I  feel this must be an issue which has been raised before, thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Fairly easy if you use `xpath`. 
if it has unique text your `xpath` should look like something like this

```
//button[.='xyz']
```

So, here "." points to the parent in HTML hierarchy and just look for text

Comment: I keep getting the exception "Unable to locate element", the code I've used is: _browser.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[.='Image']")).Click();  The text is within <a> tags, yet By.LinkText also doesn't work. Not sure if I've made an obvious mistake.

Comment: Provide your HTML snippet please

Comment: <div class="btn_typ1">
<a class="q qs" href="http://randomgeneratedmesslink">Images</a>
</div>

There are multiple of these, all using the same class, apart from the currently selected one.

Comment: Are you saying that there are multiple elements containing text 'Images'?

Comment: Only that 1 element contains the text "Images", the only other place it even appears is as an image path directory /images/folder/pic.png

Yet doing by.linktext("Images") doesn't work, so wanna try xpath.

Comment: If that's not the case then only thing I can think of is that the image is taking longer to load. For debuggig purpose you can use some static delays and see what happens. If that works there are a lot of helps out there to handle selenium waits

Answer (score 7):

You can find the link by the visible text.

`IWebElement XyzLink= _browser.FindElement(By.LinkText("xyz"));`

Also you can locate the link by partial link text as follows,

`IWebElement XyzPartialLink= _browser.FindElement(By.PartialLinkText("XYZ"));`

For example this will locate a link element which contains 'XYZ' in its text.

Comment: What happens if the link contains, say, a span with the desired text in it? E.g. <a href="/submission"><span class="nav-text">MyText</span></a>