# Selenium webdriver - click login button using "Login" text on button

Tags: selenium

I have a web page with login button. Text "Login" is there on the button. How to Click on button using that test "Login".

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25019752/select-an-element-by-the-text-it-contains-with-selenium-webdriver

Comment: Please share with me your HTML code..

Answer (score 0):

Try Xpath using contains `//input[contains(.,'Login')]` or `//input[contains(text(),'Login')]`

While using contains clause in Xpath, if you not sure about weather to verify text with id, class, text etc. user '.' only.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but when i tried like below it's gives error -  Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[contains(.,'Next')]"}

Comment: This is what i write : driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[contains(.,'Next')]")).click();

Comment: Can you point to URL you are referring or paste your HTML code for that `Next` button here ? So can debug it.

Comment: i am giving the exmaple :

Comment: driver.findElement(By.linkText("Gmail")).click();

Comment: driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='Email']")).sendKeys("Mymail");
  
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[.='Next']")).click();

Comment: `Next` is not a text but a `Value` attribute. Please use this `//input[contains(@value,'Next')]`. This should work.

Comment: why don't you go for linkText("Login").submit();

Comment: This is the reason i used [.='Next'] , so it should work with all. It is not working with @value as well. Here is what i used -  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[contains(@text,'Next']")).click();

Comment: Apologies, Here is the code driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[contains(@value,'Next']"‌​)).click();

Comment: Chaged a bit and it's working - driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='Next']"))

Comment: Nice. You can upvote the answer or marked as best/exact answer if it really helps you.

Answer (score 0):

locating element maybe correct but the page is not fully loaded, try to use  `WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement element = wait.until(       ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By....));` 
ngWebDriver could help if your website is with AngluarJS

Good luck !

Comment: While i using it with By.id it works but with By.xpath it's not responding and gives error "Unable to locate an element". It doesn't seems to be an issue with page loading.